# Diffrence Between The Following Codes

Tags: c

The Following two Codes Yield the same output but has some diffrence which i couldn't figure out

1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=1;
    while(a>0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if(a != 42)
            printf("%d\n",a);
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int x;
  for(; scanf("%d",&x) > 0 && x != 42; printf("%d\n", x));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, use of different looping instruction.

Comment: yeah Correct but the working is diffrent , that is what bothers me

Answer (score 4):

The working is different because the semantics are different because the code is different.

If you would want to rewrite the 2nd part to the 1st, you would get

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int x;
  while (scanf("%d",&x) > 0 && x != 42) {
      printf("%d\n", x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(void) {
  int a;
  while (scanf("%d",&a) > 0) {
      if (x != 42) {
          printf("%d\n", x);
      } else {
          break;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Do you see the difference? On the one, you base your decision on the variable being scanned (`x` or `a`) and on the other on the return value of `scanf()`, which is simply the number of values read:

```
while(a>0)
```

vs.

```
while (scanf("%d",&a) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case it's simple looping structure.

In the second case. The `For Loop` `arguements` like `initialization of looping variable`, `condition` and `incrementation/decremenation` are always options.

here For loop initialization is omitted, the condition `scanf("%d",&x)` will return no of values properly read from console, in case if you give any random character as input scanf return 0 and the condition `x!= 42` is obvious. printf in the incremation/decrematation place just prints.

Only when the condition fails the loop terminates.

Comment: Thanks A lot..for the Answer!